# Visual Studio 2010 debug XML web service

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  Is there a way for me to debug the XML web service from Visual Studio so I can see how the internal XML is created??

Comment: You should specify whether you mean a WCF service or a legacy ASMX service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see how the XML is created because it is created by the serialization mechanism.

Comment: How can I debug the xml document then?

Comment: There is no XML document. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The web-service method I am calling takes one parameter which I am providing with data, but when the method is executed, I get a java.Lang.NullPointerException and I am unable to determine whether I am missing data or if there is something wrong in the web service as such

Comment: Then you don't need to debug the creation of the XML - you need to see the XML that is being returned. You should use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) or the equivalent to see what XML is being returned. If you were using WCF for the service, then you could turn on message tracing through configuration and see what exactly is  being returned.

Comment: is soapUI another tool that could be used?

Comment: Of course, as long as your service can easily be called from soapUI.

Comment: Thank you for your help...I'll give it a whirl with both tools